# gulp-replace from template and project source and merge into single file

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-replace

Alright, one for the ages. The issue is I am trying to merge the structure from multiple sources into a single one. One of my sources is from the template.html which contains the base structure for index.html -source-. I trying to find a solution that replaces html block data from the source -index.html- body tag into the destination -template.html- lastly create a new merged document which outputs to -dest-.

File structure that is as follows:

- public
- ---assets
- ------template.html
- ---src
- ------app.js
- ------index.html
- ------main.css
- ---dist
- ------merged.html

I am using npm package gulp-replace (but open to other packages).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');
var copycat = require('gulp-copycat');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    // create a watch task
    gulp.task('default', function() {
        gulp.src('assets/template.html')
            .pipe(htmlreplace({
                'cssInline': {
                    src: gulp.src('sheetgmail/main.css'),
                    tpl: '<style>%s</style>'
                },
                'body': gulp.src('sheetgmail/index.html'),
                'headscript': {
                    src: null,
                    tpl: '%s'
                },
                'js': {
                    src: gulp.src('sheetgmail/app.js'),
                    tpl: "<script type='text/javascript'>%s</script>"
                },
            }, {
                keepUnassigned: false,
                keepBlockTags: true,
                resolvePaths: false
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
    });
});
```

Comment: so whats the question? what is the issue with gulp-replace?

Comment: The question is there a solution with gulp-replace that or any other NPM package that will work in targeting HTML blocks of data specifically those within the body tags of the project (index.html) file and replace with that of the template.html and output a merged document to the directory "dest"?

Comment: The issue I am experiencing is that I am able to target the project index.html file and inject it into the template file and output the merge document but it's not targeting the body data within the project index.html. Instead it takes the entire file and injects it.